# chabadlibrary.org link structure has changed, and there are now many broken links

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

chabadlibrary.org recently changed their page structure, and as such any links to that website have to be updated.

For example (from here: [How to pronounce the name of the sefer "Bnei Yso(s)cher"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10750/how-to-pronounce-the-name-of-the-sefer-bnei-ysoscher/11663) ):

> http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/admur/lkus/30/14/5/287

has become:

> http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/lkus/30/14/5/287

. Seems like a pretty easy search and replace `"default.aspx?furl=/"` with `""`.

According to this query there are 151 such broken links: http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/832303/posts-with-broken-chabadlibrary-org-links

Is there a way for the mods or admins to mass change those links, preferably without affecting the publication date, so that they don't all end up at the top of the site?

---

This would be a good place to encourage people who care about the effect broken links have on our website and user experience to check out this feature request, and upvote (if you think it is a good idea) and comment: [why not automatically archive links in questions and answers](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/why-not-automatically-archive-links-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: There's no way for the mods to do it directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok; [6 of these](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/835731) couldn't be done automatically as they contained search parameters that broke with a simple search-and-replace. I edited those manually to fix the links.

The remaining posts were re-written en mass to fix the links, and won't be bumped to the homepage. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Achabadlibrary.org%2Fbooks%2Fdefault.aspx